# Meteor.js: Error not caught on client in method call

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I am trying to throw a user defined error while updating a documents in mongoDb, if any error occures in Method. I am calling method and trying to catch the error, but i am not getting one. Error is printed only in server console. how can i catch the error in client side?

My code sample seems like this:

```
//Method

     methodName: (userData) ->
        if(Meteor.isServer and this.userId)
          User.update {_id:this.userId},{$set:{username:userData.username, "profile.name": userData.name ,"emails.$.address": userData.email}}, (error) ->
            if error and error.code == 11000
              throw new Meteor.Error 403, 'Email already in used'




//client Side

        $meteor.call('methodName',result).then ((success) ->
                console.log success // is undefined in both case, when updates and in case of error
                if success
                  console.log 'data updated'

                ), (err) ->
                  console.log err // not entered in this region
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple of misconceptions

1) A method is a synchronous call. This means if it returns or runs completely before an error is fired the error callback will not be called on the client.

This means you need to use synchronous code throughout. At the moment, you are using a callback.

You can use this approach instead:

```
Meteor.methods methodName: (userData) ->
  if Meteor.isServer and @userId
    return User.update({ _id: @userId }, $set:
      username: userData.username
      'profile.name': userData.name
      'emails.$.address': userData.email)
```

This will throw an error that will be received on the client with reason "Internal Server Error". As a 'catch-all' error. The difference between your code is there is no callback.

You can catch your specific duplicate key error using the `try..catch` pattern using this syntax.

2) `User.update {_id:this.userId}` will *always* run. You are looking for a "duplicate key", 11000, error when you update the document. This isn't the best approach to doing this. You should directly check for the email beforehand.

3) A method should `return` a value. At the moment, you don't return anything. You can only use one for the result, a callback or checking the value given back by the method. At the moment, you do both, so the result of `User.update` is `undefined`. This is why you see `undefined`. This should work:

```
Meteor.methods methodName: (userData) ->
  if Meteor.isServer and @userId
    if(User.emails.address':userData.email})) throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Email already exists");
    return User.update({ _id: @userId }, $set:
      username: userData.username
      'profile.name': userData.name
      'emails.$.address': userData.email)
  else return false
```

So here you would directly check for a user having used the email and throw the Error & update it if it's not used. There are no callbacks so it should return a value to Meteor.call on the client.

Comment: "A method is a synchronous call" ?? 
meteor's method returns a promises/callback right so, its it async??
 http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

Comment: @SureshMainali A Meteor call on the client is always asynchronous. The corresponding server side method can contain async code. However, If you want something in `result` on the client in the async callback, the corresponding server side method requires synchronous code and must `return` a value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a large amount of errors.

```
Meteor.methods({

  methodName: function(userData){

    // you have to create the $set hash programatically first
    var setHash = {
      "$set": {
        "username": userData.username,
        "profile.name": userData.name,
        // what's going on here with the dollar sign you originally had?
        "emails.0.address": userData.email
      }
    };

    if( Meteor.isServer && this.userId() ){
      // It's Users, not User
      return Users.update( { _id: this.userId() }, setHash, function(error, numberOfAffectedDocuments){
        if(error && error.code == "11000"){
          // Error names have to be a string
          throw new Meteor.error("403", "Email already in use.");
        } else {
          return "Success! The number of affected documents is " + numberOfAffectedDocuments;
      });
    };

  }

});

// in your original code you never sent your Meteor Method any arguments when calling it
Meteor.call('methodName', userDataObject, function(error, result){
  if(error){
    console.log("there was an error: ", error);
  } else {
    console.log("method call was a success: ", result);
  };
});
```

References:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user

Comment: Your method is returning inside the callback. The `Success! The num...` won't be passed on the client as it returns to the callback and not to the method.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny it will always return undefined on success case as you have it in your call back. You are answering on your own thoughts. Please be relevant

Comment: Edited to return to the method.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny I dont think any of your suggestion are relevent
//you just have re-formatted my code. Plus User is my collection that i have created nothing to do with meteor user.